Discord.js: Removing roles doesn't work when splitting code into two modules
I am making a discord app that removes a role and adds another, it was working fine when everything was in one module, but when I tried to make two more modules one for adding the role and one for removing the role, it became adding the role without removing the other one even though I didn't change any code.
index.js
const addRole = require("./addRole.js");
const removeRole = require("./removeRole.js");

...

if (allowedRoles.includes(role)) {
    let roleRemoved = false;

    allowedRoles.forEach( (id) => {
      if (!colorRemoved) {
        // "roleRemoved" variable is an attempt to expedite the process (It can be omitted)

        if (member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.id === id)) {
          removeRole(member, id);

          colorRemoved = true;
        }
      }
    });

    addRole(member, role);
 }

"allowedRoles" is an array containing a bunch of role ids.
"role" is a string containing an id of a role.
"member" is an object containing everything about the user who will obtain the role.
addRole.js
module.exports = (member, role) => {
  member.roles.add(role).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  });
};

removeRole.js
module.exports = (member, role) => {
  member.roles.remove(role).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  });
};

I tried removing removeRole.js but kept addRole.js, and the code started working again.
index.js
const addRole = require("./addRole.js");

...

if (allowedRoles.includes(role)) {
    let roleRemoved = false;

    allowedRoles.forEach( (id) => {
      if (!colorRemoved) {
        // "roleRemoved" variable is an attempt to expedite the process (It can be omitted)

        if (member.roles.cache.some((role) => role.id === id)) {
          member.roles.remove(id).catch((err) => {
             console.error(err);
             return;
          });


          colorRemoved = true;
        }
      }
    });

    addRole(member, role);
 }

Note: I don't know if this can help but when I was trying to solve the problem I noticed that (since the role I am using is colored) the color of my username changed back to default before turning again to how it was which made me conclude that the role gets removed and added back at the same time even though addRole.js and removeRole.js have different ids.

addRole fires sooner if you use removeRole. (difference of approx. 20ms)
When using removeRole, the bot removes a role and then adds another role 1-10ms later. Discord cannot process the second request in time and so it is ignored.
The solution is to add a small delay before addRole fires
setTimeout(function () {
    addRole(member, role)
}, 100)

